# How to resolve javax.enterprise.inject.IllegalProductException when using JPA repository

Tags: quarkus

I am getting exception when calling findAll method on CrudRepository in quarkus - based code.

Here is my database configuration.

```
quarkus.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
quarkus.datasource.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
quarkus.datasource.username = ZZZZ
quarkus.datasource.password = XXX
```

Here is repository code.

```java
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

    public interface FruitRepository extends CrudRepository<FruitEntity, Integer> {
    }
```

Here is client code.

```java
    import javax.inject.Inject;
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

    @Path("/fruitz")
    public class FruitController {
        @Inject
        FruitRepository fruitRepository;

        @GET
        @Produces("application/json")
        public Iterable<FruitEntity> findAll() {
            return fruitRepository.findAll();
        }
    }
```

I am getting following exception.

> Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.IllegalProductException: Normal scoped producer method may not return null: io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSourceProducer.createDefaultDataSource()
>           at io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSourceProducer_ProducerMethod_createDefaultDataSource_7c487e3ef869f878aa871e917c94f4d26d5d5c56_Bean.create(DataSourceProducer_ProducerMethod_createDefaultDataSource_7c487e3ef869f878aa871e917c94f4d26d5d5c56_Bean.zig:306)
>           at io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSourceProducer_ProducerMethod_createDefaultDataSource_7c487e3ef869f878aa871e917c94f4d26d5d5c56_Bean.create(DataSourceProducer_ProducerMethod_createDefaultDataSource_7c487e3ef869f878aa871e917c94f4d26d5d5c56_Bean.zig:244)
>           at io.quarkus.arc.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:69)
>           at io.quarkus.arc.ComputingCache$CacheFunction.lambda$apply$0(ComputingCache.java:99)
>           at io.quarkus.arc.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:26)
>           at io.quarkus.arc.ComputingCache.getValue(ComputingCache.java:41)
>           at io.quarkus.arc.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:20)
>           at io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSourceProducer_ProducerMethod_createDefaultDataSource_7c487e3ef869f878aa871e917c94f4d26d5d5c56_ClientProxy.arc$delegate(DataSourceProducer_ProducerMethod_createDefaultDataSource_7c487e3ef869f878aa871e917c94f4d26d5d5c56_ClientProxy.zig:152)
>           at io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSourceProducer_ProducerMethod_createDefaultDataSource_7c487e3ef869f878aa871e917c94f4d26d5d5c56_ClientProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProducer_ProducerMethod_createDefaultDataSource_7c487e3ef869f878aa871e917c94f4d26d5d5c56_ClientProxy.zig:23)

Answer (score 0):

You have to annotate your interface with `@Named` to make it available for injection. Also ensure to have `quarkus-jdbc-postgresql` added as a dependency.

Comment: I had quarkus-jdbc-postgresql dependency, but @Named made it work.

Comment: That was just to ensure,  but the missing annotation was needed for CDI. You can accept it as the answer.

Comment: @JohnBradsow please accept the answer if it worked for you so future readers can immediately see what the resolution was.

Comment: I am very surprised however to see `@Named`. I have never needed it in the Quarkus Spring code

Comment: Would there be any other solution. I just tried to make a simple Quarkus Crud repository. I am using MariaDB connector, quarkus 1.2.0, i think i have all the right stuff from the Quarkus tutorial, but i always got that error. I really don’t know whats going on. I tried to add the @Named annotation on every beans in my project too. There is only 3!